# Pages not using permalink

Tags: permalinks, pages

I recently changed my theme from one custom theme to another custom theme.

There were previously pages that used template files (i.e., "Blog" page uses Blog template) and now that I've changed themes the pages are not redirecting as usual.

I tried importing the old data and then each page was created twice (i.e., Blog (with permalink blog) and Blog (with permalink blog-2)).

I've tried deleting both pages and choosing to deleted them permanently.

I also tried re-creating the page using the template file (naming it "Blog" with permalink blog), but I continue to get the error:

Index of /blog
Apache Server Port 80

It seems that WP is directing to the folder /blog instead of the page with the permalink blog.

If I change the title of the page (i.e., "Test" with permalink test) and apply the template file the issue resolves. But I would like to keep the same links as the previous design.

.htaccess issue or WordPress issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting

```
Index of /blog
Apache Server Port 80
```

instead of a `404` page, you might be having a folder called `blog` in on your server. Try deleting or renaming that folder if you're not using it.

EDIT:

Here is a related question: [WP Page and Subdirectory with same name](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6373/wp-page-and-subdirectory-with-same-name)

Comment: You're spot on with interpreting the error correctly. There is, in fact, a folder named `blog` on the server. However, this folder was there before and I was able to previously use the `blog` permalink just fine. Regardless of your ability to explain this, I've accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting the permalink by clicking "Save Changes" in Settings > Permalinks in the admin page.

If that doesn't work, read the documentation of your new theme to see how it wants to create blog page. For example, some theme require you set Blog page in Settings > Reading, while some theme require you change the page setting to use Blog template. So there might be difference in how your old and new theme deal with Blog page.