# Wordpress page not taking precedence over server directory

Tags: pages, redirect, directory, server

On my wordpress site, I have a page *mysite.com/download*. On the same server I have a directory named *download*, where I store files which I need to provide on download page. So the problem is that when someone tries to access mysite.com/download, he's taken to the directory instead of the page. I have turned off the directory access for now, so it currently displays no permission to access.
I want wordpress to display the page instead of the directory. I am not sure if it's a problem with the server or wordpress. I hope someone can clarify.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6373/wp-page-and-subdirectory-with-same-name

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer!
It's an issue with the .htaccess file. I needed to write a rule in the .htaccess file for this exception, after renaming my download folder to downloads. So it still requires the folder to be renamed.

```
RewriteRule ^download/(.+)$ downloads/$1
```

This rule should be before the wordpress rules in the file. This makes sure that if someone is looking in the *mysite.com/download/folder1* sub-directory, he's actually redirected to *mysite.com/downloads/folder1*.

Ref: [WP Page and Subdirectory with same name](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6373/wp-page-and-subdirectory-with-same-name)